# Regex, better way

Tags: python, regex

How do you separate a regex, that could be matched multiple times within a string, if the delimiter is within the string, ie:
Well then 'Bang bang swing'(BBS) aota 'Bing Bong Bin'(BBB)

With the regex: "'.+'(\S+)"
It would match from Everything from 'Bang ... (BBB) instead of matching 'Bang bang swing'(BBS) and 'Bing Bong Bin'(BBB)

I have a manner of making this work with regex: '[A-z0-9-/?|q~`!@#$%^&*()_-=+ ]+'(\S+)
But this is excessive, and honestly I hate that it even works correctly.
I'm fairly new to regexes, and beginning with Pythons implementation of them is apparently not the smartest manner in which to start it.

Comment: Google `regex greedy lazy`.

Comment: You need to make it non-greedy: `'.+?'(\S+)`

Comment: Goddamn it thank you. I was heavily against using that full expression. Didn't know these things were called greedy/lazy points, so that's super helpful as well. The search brought me back to stack, and the article fully answered the question.

Comment: Note that `'.+?'\(\S+\)` is highly inefficient because of `.+?` and the fact that `\S` matches `(` and `)`. I will post my own solution once my kids go to bed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a substring from one character up to another character, *where neither can appear in-between*, you should always consider using [*negated character classes*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

> The [negated] character class **matches any character that is not in the character class**. *Unlike the dot*, **negated character classes also match (invisible) line break characters**. If you don't want a negated character class to match line breaks, you need to include the line break characters in the class. `[^0-9\r\n]` matches any character that is not a digit or a line break.

So, you can use

```
'[^']*'\([^()]*\)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fJ1lJ1/1)

Here,

- `'[^']*'` - matches `'` followed by 0 or more characters other than `'` and then followed by a `'` again
- `\(` - matches a literal `)` (it must be escaped)
- `[^()]*` - matches 0 or more characters other than `(` and `)` (they do not have to be escaped inside a character class)
- `\)` - matches a literal `)` (must be escaped outside a character class).

If you might have 1 or more single quotes before `(...)` part, you will need an unrolled lazy matching regex:

```
'[^']*(?:'(?!\([^()]*\))[^']*)*'\([^()]*\)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fJ1lJ1/2).

Here, the `'[^']*(?:'(?!\([^()]*\))[^']*)*'` is matching the same as `'.*?'` with DOTALL flag, but is much more efficient due to the linear regex execution. See [more about unrolling regex technique here](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop).

**EDIT:**

When input strings are not complex and short, lazy dot matching turns out more efficient. However, when complexity grows, lazy dot matching may cause issues.

Comment: But then the unrolled sequence requires more than twice the steps as the lazy one. I can see situations in which it'd be more useful though. It's actually better because of the possibility of an apostrophe somewhere even though it wouldn't match the full format.  Never know how someone's input may look.

Comment: It depends on the input string length. With short strings, lazy dot matching is OK, when you add 200+ symbols inbetween, the picture will be different.

Comment: Well the code will most likely be working on sentences, and they should be relatively short. I'm going to try and find manners in which the regex breaks though if I can find one within a reasonable structure point, then I will change it up. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

How about this regular expression

```
'.+?'\(\S+\)
```

Comment: Yes this sequence worked. the lazy point also helped me make the rest of my regexes much more efficient. Reading through the documentation a bit more heavily right now.

Comment: Once you start having problems with lazy subpatterns, google `unroll the loop regex` and study that approach which is times more efficient than lazy matching.

Comment: @stribizhev thanks for the inputs :) i'm eager to learn it all :)

Comment: @stribizhev Will do, I'm trying to make my parsing as fast as is possible, and not mess myself up too much.

Comment: This answer is below standards for me, more explanation is in the comments to the question than in your answer.